# Setting JRE for TPTP profiling

Tags: java, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I am trying to profile a project loads some external libraries which depends on cygwin.
In order to do so, I need to use a native java launcher similar to the one suggested in [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/cvm.aspx).

In the running and debugging configurations, there's a place to manually set the JRE so I was able to configure the project to run using my own java-launcher.exe instead of the default java executable. I can't, however, seem to be able to do the same with the TPTP profiler configuration.

Do you have any suggestions how to manually set the JRE, or perhaps suggest a different profiler I could use?